# Topology of $S^2 \times S^2 \setminus Diagonal = S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \{ (x,x): x\in S^2 \} $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I am interested in understanding the topology of the space;

$ X  = S^2 \times S^2 \setminus Diagonal = S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \{ (x,x): x\in S^2 \} = \{ (x,y)\in S^2 \times S^2 : x \neq y \} $

I considered another example, namely $ Y = S^1 \times S^1 \setminus Diagonal = S^1 \times S^1 \setminus \{ (x,x): x\in S^1 \} $.

Considering the planar representation of the torus as a square under proper identifications, removing the diagonal leaves an annulus: When we remove the diagonal from the square, we end up with two disconnected triangles and shifting one to the top of the other realizes the identification on one side. Then we end up with a rectangle with only one opposite sides to be identified and identifying these two sides gives us an annulus.

Maybe with a similar argument, can we understand the topology of the space $ X  = S^2 \times S^2 \setminus Diagonal = S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \{ (x,x): x\in S^2 \}  $ ?

Any kind of answer or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the projection $X \to S^2$ on the first component. The fiber of this map over $x \in S^2$ is $S^2 \backslash \{x\} \cong \Bbb R^2$. This means that your space is a family of $2$-planes over the sphere. We can see it as a family of vector spaces, with origin given by $\{(a,-a) : a \in S^2\}$. The exact identification is a bit delicate to write down but I believe it's true. In particular this means $X$ retracts onto $S^2$.

To understand $X$ we just need to find its Euler class $e(X)$ of the vector bundle. I won't write down the definition but here is an example : over $S^1$ there are two possibilities : $e(X) = 0$ and $X = S^1 \times \Bbb R$ (i.e the annulus you found) or $e(X) = 1$ and $X$ is a Moebius band.

To find $e(X)$ we need to take a family of vectors in $X$ and see how many zeroes and poles we found. We take then $e(X) = \#zeroes - \#poles$. Now we take a little rotation around the $z$-axis, say $r : S^2 \to S^2$. This gives $s : S^2 \to X, (x,r(x))$. In fact, $s$ is not defined at the north pole and the south pole, giving two poles. There are 4 zeroes so we find $e(X) = 2$ i.e $X = TS^2$.

To recover back your previous answer, we see that $s : S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1, t \mapsto (t, t+\pi/2)$ has no zero or poles, so it means that $e(X) = 0$ and we find indeed an annulus.

**Remark** : In fact, I believe we should always have $TS^n \cong \{(x,y) \in S^n : x \neq y\}$. A vague argument is that the normal bundle of the diagonal $\Delta \subset X \times X$ is always isomorphic to the tangent bundle of $X$. Not sure how to exactly apply it but it seems a start ... (in fact see the comment by Balarka Sen. I should say I need to think a bit more about it)

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the (unordered) [configuration space of two points on the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(mathematics)). Its fundamental group is given by the $2$-string pure sphere braid group which happens to just be trivial in the case of $2$ strings.

There is plenty of literature on these spaces.

Comment: I feel a bit confused : the projection on the first component has fiber $\Bbb R^2$, so this is a topological vector bundle on $S^2$, in particular this should retract on $S^2$. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're choosing as the base space of the bundle. You can't just choose $S^2 \times \{1\}$ for instance, because for every $x \in S^2$, the point $(x,x)$ is not in our space.

Comment: The zero section is $\{(x,-x) : x \in S^2\}$. In fact if I'm not mistaken this space should be topologically the tangent bundle of the sphere.

Comment: Could you explicitly write the bundle down? I'm having a hard time seeing it. It's possible you're right, but then that contradicts the (as far as I was aware very well known) result that the fundamental group of the unordered configuration space is the braid group on the space - in fact, this is normally taken as the definition.

Comment: I can certainly try to do it, if it's false at least it will give an explicit example of a map with fibers $\Bbb R^2$ which is not a vector bundle which is already interesting

Comment: In this PDF : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjjhKPomc7bAhWBFxQKHQb1CbsQFghJMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mimuw.edu.pl%2F~sjack%2Fprosem%2FCohen_Singapore.final.24.december.2008.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ogpNdifdhZJCUxf2st-zn
It is written page 4 that Conf(S^n,2) retracts on $S^2$. Do you have a reference for the fact you wrote ?

Comment: Ah I see the problem now! The fundamental group of $Conf(M,n)$ is the $n$-string **pure** braid group on $M$, not the full braid group. My mistake, sorry. The full braid group is given as the fundamental group of the quotient by the action of the symmetric group on the configuration space (i.e., the ordered configuration space).

Comment: Ok I should have seen it. But unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how to write down trivialization. Anyway I wrote down my solution, tell me if this looks ok !

Comment: The normal bundle of the diagonal in $S^2 \times S^2$ is exactly the tangent bundle of $S^2$. You can find this as an exercise somewhere in standard textbooks such as Guillemin-Pollack say. So $S^2 \times S^2$ is just the fiberwise compactification of the tangent bundle of $S^2$. (It is kind of weird to think that the self-intersection number of the diagonal in $S^2 \times S^2$ is $2$, not $0$, though. Is there a braid theoretic interpretation of that using your identification, @DanRust?)

Comment: @BalarkaSen : it was exactly the argument I was thinking about. Ok anyway I wrote an answer now :)

Comment: @BalarkaSen : I agree with the first part of your message. How do you conclude that $S^2 \times S^2$ is the fiberwise compactification of $TS^2$ ? (It would indeed resolve the problem).
I think there should be also an interpreation in algebraic geometry since $S^2 \times S^2$ is a complex quadric in $\Bbb P^3$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet $S^2 \times S^2$ has a diagonal and an antidiagonal consisting of points of the form $(x, -x)$. If you throw away the antidiagonal (which is a copy of $S^2$), it becomes a $2$-plane bundle on the diagonal $S^2$ whose unit (modulo some choice of bundle metric) disk bundle is the normal bundle, i.e., $TS^2$. Therefore $S^2 \times S^2$ minus antidiagonal is, as a $2$-plane bundle, $TS^2$ as well. Adding the antidiagonal is tantamount to adding the section at infinity, which gives the fiberwise compactification.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Ah I see this is very nice, many thanks for the explanation.